# How can I convert an R data frame with a single column into a corpus for tm such that each row is taken as a document?

Tags: r, tm

I wanted to use the `findAssocs` command of the `tm` package, but it works only when there are multiple documents in the corpus. Instead, I have a one-column data frame where each row comprises text from a Tweet. Is it possible to convert this into a corpus which takes each row as a new document?

```
VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)
TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 71, documents: 1)
```

I have 10 rows of data that Iwish it to be converted as

```
VCorpus (documents: 10, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)
TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 71, documents: 10)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you read the `tm`-vignette first before proceeding. Answer to your specific question below.

Create example data:

```
txt <- strsplit("I wanted to use the findAssocs of the tm package. but it works only when there are more than one documents in the corpus. I have a data frame table which has one column and each row has a tweet text. Is it possible to convert the into a corpus which takes each row as a new document?", split=" ")[[1]]
data <- data.frame(text=txt, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data[1:5, ]
```

Import your data into a "Source", your "Source" into a "Corpus", and then make a TDM out of your "Corpus":

```
library(tm)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Corpus(DataframeSource(data)))

show(tdm)
#A term-document matrix (35 terms, 58 documents)
#
#Non-/sparse entries: 43/1987
#Sparsity           : 98%
#Maximal term length: 10 
#Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

str(tdm)
#List of 6
# $ i       : int [1:43] 32 31 28 12 28 21 3 35 20 33 ...
# $ j       : int [1:43] 2 4 5 6 8 10 11 13 14 15 ...
# $ v       : num [1:43] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ nrow    : int 35
# $ ncol    : int 58
# $ dimnames:List of 2
#  ..$ Terms: chr [1:35] "and" "are" "but" "column" ...
#  ..$ Docs : chr [1:58] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
# - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "TermDocumentMatrix" "simple_triplet_matrix"
# - attr(*, "Weighting")= chr [1:2] "term frequency" "tf"
```